# jQuery: Adding an inline function call based on an inline conditional... is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've never really run into this in the past, so I'm curious. Can you do the following in some manner?

I am using the Datatables jQuery plug-in. Here's my basic call:

```
var oTable = $("#example").dataTable();
```

I have a property in a class called EnableInlineEdit. If it is true, I want to add a function call inline:

```
var oTable = $("#example").dataTable().makeEditable();
```

This would enable the jEditable plug-in to work. I have a lot more options added to the Datatable plug-in regularly that I haven't included, so simply making a conditional if/else and creating two separate calls in out of the question. I would be doubling the size of a massive file by doing that. Is there a way to somehow create an inline conditional to add the .makeEditable onto the end of the Datatable initialization without creating two exact copies of the code with one just having the .makeEditable() on it?

Comment: My question is... can I do something like: .dataTable().<inline conditional to call .makeEditable()>. If I if/else and then filter the entire document, I would be duplicating a ton of code for a simple addition of .makeEditable().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
var oTable = var oTable = $("#example").dataTable();
if (whatever) {
    oTable.makeEditable();
}
```

Comment: I thought of this as well. I'll try this too.

Answer (score 1):

Make a named function that returns the value in question.

```
function getval() {
    return some.value; // the value that decides if .makeEditable should run
}
```

Then add a `.filter` call to the chain.

```
var oTable = $("#example").dataTable().filter(getval).makeEditable();
```

If `getval` returns a truthy value, `.makeEditable()` will be invoked. Otherwise not.

If you need `oTable` to refer to the original element(s), then add `.end()` to the end of the chain.

```
var oTable = $("#example").dataTable().filter(getval).makeEditable().end();
```

---

This may be a better solution.

Just include the `.makeEditable()` calls, and if `EnableInlineEdit` is `false`, then overwrite the function *(or add the function as the case may be)*.

```
if (EnableInlineEdit === false)
    jQuery.fn.makeEditable = function() { return this; };
```

So now if `EnableInlineEdit` is `false`, the `makeEditable` is a function that does nothing but returns the jQuery object so chaining can continue.

Comment: @jlrolin: See my update. You'll need an `.end()` call if you want to restore the original elements matched by the selector.

Comment: @jlrolin: I added another solution that may be better.